# Patator error when starting brute

Tags: python

I tried to use [patator](https://github.com/lanjelot/patator) for brute forcing RDP login but I am receiving an error.

I ran the command as follows:

```
python patator.py rdp_login host=FILE0 user=FILE1 password=FILE2 \
  0=ipList.txt 1=login.txt 2=pass.txt \
  -x ignore,reset,retry:code=500 \
  -x ignore:mesg='Login incorrect.' \
  -x ignore:mesg='Password incorrect.' \
  -x ignore:fgrep='Authrntication failed'
```

Here is error:

```
File "patator.py", line 4709, in <module>
powder = ctrl(module, [name] + sys.argv[1:])
File "patator.py", line 1487, in __init__
self.update_actions(x)
File "patator.py", line 1505, in update_actions
raise ValueError('Unsupported action: %s' % name)
ValueError: Unsupported action: reset
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your questions for any reason.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: @Kotov222 If you want to delete your question, you have the ability to do that.  Mods - when I flagged this as VLQ, it was when Kotov had changed the body content to gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

Different modules support different actions.  `reset` is not supported for RDP, as you can see from the [`rdp_login`](https://github.com/lanjelot/patator/blob/7004b26c9801617b19e342675bc19964f1a25ffe/patator.py#L3725) class definition.